# Selenium returns an empty html body

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, selenium, aws-lambda

I am running selenium from AWS lambda, to automate a process, I was getting an error for element not found, and when I printed the page source it seems like it is actually empty, I have tried sleep for 30 seconds, without success, this works as expected  locally

```
from time import sleep
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
    from secretsx import get_secret_values



def main():
 chrome_options = Options()  
chrome_options.binary_location = '/opt/headless-chromium'
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")  
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--single-process')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')

driver = webdriver.Chrome('/opt/chromedriver',options=chrome_options)

driver.get(mypage)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(30) 

print(driver.page_source) #this returns <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head></head><body></body></html>
```

Comment: The site is probably detecting you're accessing it in an automated fashion (possibly by knowing the IP address is in the AWS range, since you say it works locally) and declining to provide a useful response.

Comment: Is the url a public url?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the issue was actually related to SSL certs, you can setup selenium to ignore it

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities


desired_capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.CHROME.copy()
desired_capabilities['acceptInsecureCerts'] = True

driver = webdriver.Chrome('/opt/chromedriver',options=chrome_options,desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)
```

I hope this is helpful for somebody haha since I spent 6 hours looking for an answer

Comment: Please.  Consider edit your post using ``` .  This way it will show better format to users.  Check [hou to edit your code](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)

Comment: Bad markdown code format

Comment: Can you post how your code looks like?
Have you add that to webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver', options=options, desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities) ?

Answer (score 0):

You saved me from spending a few hours on this problem. My code looked like this:

```
    options = Options()
    options.add_argument('--headless')
    options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
    options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')    
    desired_capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.CHROME.copy() 
    desired_capabilities['acceptInsecureCerts'] = True
    browser = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver', options=options, desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)
```